# How to assign values to properties dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

```
I have below method on service layer which will be called from different controller with different actionType(parameter to my method). 
 
   public async  Task<OutPutList[]> GetMyDataAsync(string actionType)
        {
            var request = new getMyDataRequest
            {
                getMyDatas = new getMyDatas
                {
                    AFlag= false,
                    AFlagSpecified = false,
                    BFlag=false,
                    BFlagSpecified=false,
                    cFlag=false,
                    cFlagSpecified=false,
                    commonproperty= ""
                }
            };
    
          return await _myService.method(request);
    
        }
```

If the actionType is specified as "A" , the AFlag and AFlagSpecified properties value to be set as "True" . And if i specify actionType as B then BFlag and BFlagSpecified values to be set as true and AFlag will be false.how this can be done dynamically or in any smpler way? I am having around 12 actiontypes and if i create different request object then i need to write 12 if else condition. Can this be simplified with minimum code.

Comment: My suggestion would be to pass the action type directly as well. That way, the service method can act on it directly, instead of _also_ having to check for each of those flag properties.

Comment: sorry,didnt get it clearly

Comment: Is it possible to surround the logic code with `if-else if-else if-else` ? I mean you can check the `actionType` and new different `getMyDatas`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/reflection) to make your code dynamic.

To make you understand more, You can look below code

**getMyDatas.cs**

```
public class getMyDatas
{
  public bool AFlag { get; set; }
  public bool BFlag { get; set; }
  public bool CFlag { get; set; }
}
```

**Program.cs**

```
using StackOverFlowTest;
using System;
using System.Reflection;

//input
string actionType = "A";

//Business
var Data = new getMyDatas();

PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(getMyDatas).GetProperties();
foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
    property.SetValue(Data, Convert.ChangeType(property.Name.StartsWith(actionType), property.PropertyType), null);
}

//Testing
Console.WriteLine(Data.AFlag);
Console.WriteLine(Data.BFlag);
Console.WriteLine(Data.CFlag);
```

Shortly, I check if property name starts with input

Comment: since the Data Class contains a property (eg commonproperty) which is a string . I get the error" object doesn't match target type"

Comment: i was able to set the bool property . is there any way to change te value of a string parameter with a value. Like in the example commonproperty= "" this to be set with a value.

Comment: you can use the same line for this with a little difference
`property.SetValue(Data, Convert.ChangeType("", property.PropertyType), null);`